# Rotate 3d shape in path

Tags: trigonometry, 3d, spectral-radius

It seems very simple but I am not able to figure it out

let's say I have Plane (yellow) it needs be in border when moved with BLUE direction arrow  [image]

I have value that needs to be moved for example user moves blue arrow

value to be moved =  dotVector ( normalizedDirection , forward vector)  * magnitude

Arrow to move object is rotated like so Z axis will be direction of movement , So this value will be in Z axis to move object

I have the center object + I have the radius of the circle ,

How can I Find X  Value so it always be in circle ( I don't care about up direction)

Expected result - Yellow plane should follow the path where 3d Sphere are placed

Code to move the Model

```
 let zDepth = sceneView.projectPoint(selectedAxis.position).z
        let touch3D = SCNVector3(Float(touch2D.x), Float(touch2D.y), zDepth)
        let touchPosition = sceneView.unprojectPoint(touch3D)
        
        let touchDelta = touchPosition - lastTouchPosition!
        let distance = touchDelta.magnitude
        let direction = touchDelta.normalized
        let zTranslation = distance * SCNVector3.dotVector(a: selectedAxis.forward, b: direction)
        
        selectedAxis.localTranslate(by: SCNVector3(0, 0, zTranslation))
```

Solution :

What I did
the vector where to  move let's say A

find the angle using arc tan ( A.z, A.x)  here y is 0 for all models so

from the answer of the **Quarter Lemon**

for radius 20

```
let xnext =  (cos(angle)) * 20 
let yNext = (sin(angle)) * 20
```

and now it will be move in circle only

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to clarify which circle are you talking about.  The picture provided has spheres in it, not circles.  Which sphere are you talking about ?

Comment: Also, what does the yellow plane have to do with anything ?

Comment: @QuarterLemon 1 ) Circle means - the area in all sphere are placed 
2) Yellow Plane should be moved  around the sphere

Comment: Your question is really hard to understand.  If you want answers, you should try and clarify the various variables you have in your problem.

Comment: To echo Quarter Lemon, it might help to describe what the interaction is intended to do. For example, "The user can click the blue arrow and drag it around the circle. I want the yellow plane and the arrows to more along the circle so that the blue arrow stays tangent to the circle, the three arrows remain orthonormal, and the yellow plane stays at the same angle from the blue arrow." Or whatever....

Comment: @QuarterLemon  GOAL is - User will move Yellow plane With Arrows  - that needs to follow the circular path ( created with spheres )

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang  Thanks !! , Apology I am not god in math terms so I couldn't explain it  better - That I need   **I want the yellow plane and the arrows to more along the circle**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say the circle of spheres is in the $xy$ plane.  Let the radius of that circle be $r$.  Let's also say that we have $N$ spheres, and that their centers are distributed evenly on the circumference of the circle.  It would follow that the angular separation between two adjacent spheres is $\phi = \dfrac{2\pi}{N}$.  Then assuming one of the centers lies on the $x$-axis, then the coordinates of $i$-th center will be

$ C_i = (r \cos\left( (i-1) \phi \right) , r \sin \left( (i-1) \phi \right) , 0 ) \hspace{20pt} i = 1, 2, ..., N$

Next, we have the yellow plane which passes through the center of the first sphere, and has a normal vector $U$ with an arbitrary orientation.  And we have three vectors used for moving the yellow plane, and they are the unit vectors $V_B, V_R, V_G $ (Blue, Red, Green).  These vectors can point in any direction as well, as long as they are perpendicular to each other, i.e. $V_G \perp V_B$ and $V_G \perp V_R $ and $V_B \perp V_R $.  Define the matrix $R$ as follows

$R = \left[ V_B, V_R, V_G \right] $

Then $R$ is a rotation matrix that specifies the orientation of the various possible movements:  Forward/Backward along $V_B$, Left/Right along $V_R$, Up/Down along $ V_G$.

Now suppose we want to move (translate) the yellow plane to the next sphere center, then the translation vector is given by

$ \Delta P = C_{i+1} - C_{i} = r ( \cos (i \phi) - \cos( (i-1) \phi) , \sin (i \phi) - \sin( (i-1) \phi), 0) $

To find the displacement vector $d = (d_B, d_R, d_G)$ we note that

$ \Delta P = R d $

Hence

$d = R^{-1} \Delta P = R^T \Delta P $

And this will give us all of the three required displacements.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I am able to get it correct with your answer !! ,
 Now next step is I. need to achieve the same thing with Bézier curve  - yellow plane should follow the curve